# Connection fail with epoll

Tags: sockets, network-programming, epoll

I create a network lib using EPOLL. When I connect to an address that cannot ping, my network lib detect connection fails after 70 seconds from requesting open connection. I was set timeout for socket but it could not resolve this problem. Anyone saw the same problem?

Comment: Show your code, there are many ways to mess this up.

Comment: I monitored all flags (EPOLLIN, EPOLLOUT, EPOLLERR, EPOLLHUP, EPOLLRDHUP) but no flags was raised until more than 1 minute pass.